# Multiple 'pages' in a single entry

Tags: pages

Scoping out a project that is going to be for Training Courses. Each Course will have a range of Topics and each topic will have a sequence of content followed by a Quiz and finally a summary (including quiz results). A notional structure of the content might look like this.

- Course

  - Topic

    - Content
    - Content
    - Content
    - Quiz
  - Topic

    - Content
    - Content
    - Content
    - Quiz
  - Topic

    - Content
    - Content
    - Content
    - Quiz
  - Summary

As the Topics need to be shared across courses, I'll be creating a Course entry that then uses a relationship field to specific the Topics within it. My problem at the moment is how I might create a set of pages within a Topic...it's almost like entries within an entry.

For the quiz component I'm either going to employ the 4-ee.com or eeXam addon, but still evaluating this as they have their own set of problems.

Has anyone any insight into how I might do the Topic pages? My initial thought was to use a Matrix field which each row being a page.

Comment: You might find this thread useful http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/display-entries-assigned-exclusively-to-a-parent-category/10038#10038

Comment: Thanks James, I can imagine though with making the pages another entry, that there becomes a potential problem of tracking from an authors point of view which pages could belong where. I think there would need to be some form of arbitrary naming convention or something...but happy to be proved wrong. I can see there ending up being 100's of these 'Topic' pages spread out over the 20 or so courses that make up the course library my client will have. I guess to make finding a specific page easier, provide an edit link on the front end to quick access a specific page within context.

Answer (score 1):

Would Playa work for this?

Create a channel for your "pages".
Create a Playa field within your courses channel and hook it up to the Pages channel.

The admin would then be able to select which pages are associated to the course.

Other than that I might also go with a Matrix field with each row being a "page" but really it depends on how complex the pages were and how many fields I would need for each page. Also the complexity of the navigation might be an issue.

As I think about it I would probably go with the Playa option.

Comment: Well the idea is to already do that between Course and Topics. It's the Topics that require the 'pages'. The Matrix approach is looking like the go on this one. It allows me to also look at doing a 'thermometer' like device to show progress through a topic too.

Comment: OK, I'd link Topics and Pages via Playa :)  As for the 'thermometer', you would still be able to do this via Playa maybe by storing the ids of any completed pages/topics within a custom member field.